# Invalid id value for this SObject type on save from Eclipse

Tags: unit-test, force.com, eclipse

When saving my code from the Eclipse Force.com IDE, I get a bunch of errors like:

```
Invalid id value for this SObject type: 001i000000qE9TfAAK
```

What's mystifying about this is that I get this error on several test classes on line numbers that don't exist. I even get it on my project itself several times. Here is a screenshot of the errors (company name on the project redacted):

[image: screenshot]

I've checked what I believe to be the obvious:

- Nowhere is an id like `001i000000qE9TfAAK` hardcoded.
- All the points where an id is set, I made sure they were the correct data types.

What's even more mystifying here is that the tests run just fine within Salesforce itself. These strange errors are only happening in the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr this is a datatype mismatch issue

This type of error is from mismatched datatypes of ids. Check the following:

(1) Don't use hard-coded ids, even if you know the id is of the same datatype. For example:

```
Account a = '001i000000qE9TfAAK';
```

This is a bad idea because if your code ends up being used in other Salesforce organizations, this hardcoded id will likely point to something else (or nothing). See [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25610/class-test-invalid-id-value-for-this-sobject-type-how-to-reference-id-in-tes?rq=1) for an example of a similar error that happened with hardcoded values.

(2) When setting an id, make sure the datatype of the id matches the variable you're setting it with. This is bad and will lead to an error like the one in the question:

```
Host__c h = new Host__c();
Rate_Card__c r = new Rate_Card__c();
Show__c s = new Show__c(Host__c=r.id);
```

In this case, the Show constructor is being passed an already initialized Host object. However, the Host object being passed to the constructor is r.id, which is of datatype Rate_Card__c. An error like this is probably the result of a typo, and unfortunately Eclipse gets confused and its errors don't reflect the correct location in the code of the typo.

(3) When passing ids to other methods, make sure the datatype that the method expects matches with what you're sending to it. Again, this can be the result of a typo, and again Eclipse isn't very useful in its error messages.

In the end, for me the issue was #3. I was passing one object's ids in in a `list<id>` to a method that was expecting a different type of id. Eclipse was bombing out on the test run, but it was so confused that it didn't know where to mark the error. I found this by backtracking and commenting my code out in reverse chronological order. Eventually the error when away, so I knew what area of my code must be causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. Are you positive your Eclipse project is pointing to the right organisation? For example after such test run can you go to Setup > Deploy > Deployment Status and look for rows with "Validate: Failed".
2. Is this sandbox or production? Attempt to save class in project pointing to production will result in a deployment attempt = this "save error" might be actually a test class failing during deployment. Maybe you're sending changes one class at a time and they should be a proper "all or nothing" package because they depend on each other.
3. Assuming it's sandbox: Is this on save or on attempt to run unit tests? If on save - can you hit "Compile all classes" in the web interface? Can you refresh the project from server (should make the errors disappear, maybe it's some stale error) and try again?
4. If it's from unit test execution. Look closer into the debug log of that unit test. The line numbers are suspiciously similar. Maybe you have some helper method that inserts test data in your unit test and something fails there.
5. The Id doesn't have to be hardcoded. The sequence of Ids in that screenshot suggests these are inserted when the test runs. But if it's hardcoded - hit Ctrl+H and search for he 15-char version to be on the safe side too: `001i000000qE9Tf`

I suspect it's a messed up project that points to production = silently runs tests during file save. And I think it's an error from unit test and not compile-time error because Id compatibility checks are done at runtime. This compiles fine:

```
Account a = new Account(Id = UserInfo.getUserId());
```

Comment: 1. Org is correct. I've been saving files to the org just fine before today. 2. Production. Yes, I realize this is resulting in a deploy attempt. 3. Not sandbox. 4. I believe it's from a unit test as well, I just can't figure out where. I guess I could just start commenting things out and see what happens. 5. I just triple checked by searching as you suggested and found nothing hardcoded.

Comment: Try a proper deployment. Right click that file (or on whole "classes" directory?), Force.com > Deploy to server. Use either real deployment or "validate only". You'll get more meaningful listing of failures and the debug log of whole operation (capped at 2 MB I think so depending on how many tests you have you might have to tweak the debug log settings on the more verbose classes & triggers.